# Twitter embedded buttons just showing as links

Tags: html, twitter, embed

For some reason Twitter buttons aren't working on my site.

Neither the follow button or tweet button show properly. Instead they just show as standard a href links.

Here's an example:

http://www.homestudiocenter.com/twitter-follow-test/

I can clearly see that the class has been reference:

```html
<a class="twitter-follow-button" href="https://twitter.com/RobMayzes" data-size="large">Follow @RobMayzes</a>
```

And here is the code for the Tweet button, which is also clearly shown in page source:

```html
<a class="twitter-share-button"
  href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet">
Tweet</a>
```

Have tried everything!

Comment: You need the `script` code provided by twitter to create the button. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code instead:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/RobMayzes" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @RobMayzes</a>

<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet">Tweet</a>

<script>
    ! function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
        if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }
    }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
</script>
```

The above script is compulsory to display the proper buttons.

Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/tusharkhatiwada/cxakLpaw/